# array question filter

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

```
Array(
[MainArray]=>Array
    (
 [myarray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1234
                    [url] => google.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 675677
                    [url] => stackoverflow.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 234234
                    [url] => test.com
                )

        )
    )
 )
```

what i want is to choose the url that meets the id
 so if id is 1234, url should be google.com

I have this code

```
 foreach($MainArray['myarray'] as $arr){
            $url = $arr['url'];

}
```

but it gives me all three. I need to filter them
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($MainArray['myarray'] as $arr)
{
  if ($arr['id'] == 1234)
  {
    $url = $arr['url'];
    break;
  }
}
```